# What's the "community wiki" checkbox used for?

Tags: discussion

I was just answering on question on the main site and noticed a tiny checkbox below the post box - [ ] community wiki. Wondering what that's used for?

Comment: Good answer here:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

See also:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55888/when-to-mark-the-community-wiki-checkbox-on-a-new-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting "Community Wiki" checkbox that is available below the answer box will in consequence: "Marking an answer community wiki encourages others to edit it by lowering the reputation barrier required to edit. However, you will not gain any upvote reputation from it. This cannot be undone."
I assume that would be used when the answer is not perfect and one would want to invite others to update/correct it rather then take the ownership of the whole answer (and gain points for it)

Comment: The Community Wiki feature has been largely deprecated, and it has been almost entirely replaced by the 'suggested edit' feature as a way to encourage broader participation in editing. [**The Future of Community Wiki**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)